# "Не думая". Нужно ли обособить это деепричастие?

Tags: пунктуация, деепричастия

> Я_первым делом_не думая_села за деревянный стол.

Нужно ли "не думая" или "первым делом" обособлять запятыми? Я склоняюсь к "нет", но... как-то сомневаюсь.

Answer (score 2):

Мне видится так:

Я первым делом, не думая, села за деревянный стол.

Первым делом = сначала, это наречие, не вводное слово, а вот **не думая** - всё-таки деепричастие, если бы это было наречие, оно стояло бы в конце предложения, после глагола: Я села за стол не думая.

Comment: Корректно ли деепричастие с частицей *не* называть  деепричастным **оборотом**?

Comment: Нет, конечно, это одиночное деепричастие, зарапортовалась, сейчас поправлю.

Answer (score 2):

**Я первым делом, не думая, села за деревянный стол.**

Обособлять "первым делом" я бы не стал. Возможно, такое обособление не было бы ошибкой, но уж очень этот вариант специфичный, "авторский".

Обойтись вообще без запятых не получается, хотя бы потому, что предложение становится неясным:  "первым делом не думая" или "не думая села".

Остается одно – обособить причастие с частицей *не*. Правилами это не запрещено.

Answer (score 1):

**Обособление зависит от контекста.**

*Первым делом* ― наречие, обычно не обособляется, но  может быть обособлено, если автор захочет его выделить.

*Не думая* ― деепричастие может обособляться или не обособляться, но чаще обособляется не одиночное деепричастие, а оборот.

Пример **без обособления в середине предложения:**

И она **не думая** протянула ладонь в ответ, напечатала: [Майя Кучерская. Тетя Мотя // «Знамя», 2012]

Варианты:

1) *Я, первым делом, не думая  села за деревянный стол.*

2) *Я первым делом, не думая, села за деревянный стол.*